# ArrayList put a field in each map of the list according to the value of another arrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, java-stream

I have an arraylist:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "number": "229425941           ",
            "CURRENCY": "EUR",
            "account": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
            "branch": "0154",
            "product": "geia",
            "service": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
            "amount": 20000,
            "expDate": "2019-09-20",
            "bank": "0026",
            "name": "A name        "
        },
        {
            "number": "229425941           ",
            "CURRENCY": "EUR",
            "account": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
            "branch": "0154",
            "product": "geia",
            "service": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
            "amount": 20000,
            "expDate": "2019-09-20",
            "bank": "0027",
            "name": "A name        "
        },
    ]
}
```

and I have a second arraylist which contains details for each bank. The list is this:

```
"details": [
        {
            "bankCode": "010",
            "bankDescription": "BANK",
        },
        {
            "bankCode": "011",
            "bankDescription": "NATIONAL",
        },
        {
            "bankCode": "012",
            "bankDescription": "ALPHA",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to loop through the first list and put the `bankDescription` field in each object of the list according to the `bankCode` and the `bankDescription` of the second list. I made a stream for the first arrayList:

```
firtsList.stream().forEach(a -> {
            a.put();
        });
```

My guess is that somehow to loop through the second list but I don't know an efficient way. My output must be something like this:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "number": "229425941           ",
            "CURRENCY": "EUR",
            "account": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
            "branch": "0154",
            "product": "geia",
            "service": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
            "amount": 20000,
            "expDate": "2019-09-20",
            "bank": "010",
            "bankDesc: "BANK"
            "name": "A name        "
        },
        {
            "number": "229425941           ",
            "CURRENCY": "EUR",
            "account": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
            "branch": "0154",
            "product": "geia",
            "service": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
            "amount": 20000,
            "expDate": "2019-09-20",
            "bank": "011",
            "bankDesc: "NATIONAL"
            "name": "A name        "
        },
    ]
}

secondList.stream().filter(bic -> firstList.stream()
                .anyMatch(c -> StringUtils.substring((String) c.get("bankDesc"), 1, 3)
                .equals(bic.get("bankCode"))));
```

Comment: First, you need to show us which data structures in Java you are using to represent the above JSONs. Or are you trying to edit the JSON document this way? Please include the applicable code in your question. In general, I'd make the bank information a `Map` and use that, but your question is too abstract at the moment.

Comment: I use these lists: Map<String, Object> p = message.getPayload();
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> bankDetails = ( ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) p.get("details");
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> chequesInCollateralList = ( ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) chequesInCollateralMap.get("response");

Comment: They told me to use filter to the stream()

Comment: Please add the information into the question by pressing on the [edit] link. Don't use comments for code, it is not formatted properly. Remember to format it in the question by selecting it and pressing the `{}` button. In any case, try to avoid maps to `Object` and use a real class instead. And using `filter` would be inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Have a model/dto to simplify the process. You can use objectMapper to map Json directly into POJO.

Assuming you disregard all advice and proceed with Json/Map, here's how you can proceed:

```
//Build a dictionary from the data
Map<String, String> bankCodeToDescriptionMap = secondList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v.get("bankCode"), v -> v.get("bankDescription")));

firstList.stream().forEach(a -> {
            a.put("bankDescription", bankCodeToDescriptionMap.get(v.get("bankCode")));
        });
```

Do not iterate over the list for each value. It will be too slow

Comment: Can i use filter to the stream() to achieve the desired result?

Comment: ALSO it IS shown a syntax error in v.get("bankDescription")

Comment: If you use filters, it will iterate through the list each time, increasing the complexity. 
Added brackets to solve for syntax error